# Amtega8a + Terminal Real term

Tags: c, avr, atmega

uploaded the code to the atmega

```
# define F_CPU 1000000UL
//#include <stddef.h>
#include <avr\io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

//zmienne dot. odbioru danych
volatile unsigned char odb_x;       //odebrana liczba X
volatile unsigned char odb_flaga =0;//flaga informująca main o odebraniu liczby

//bufor znaków ze wzorem funkcji, który wysyłamy po starcie programu
volatile unsigned int usart_bufor_ind;           //indeks bufora nadawania
char usart_bufor[30] = "y = 0.3187x^2 + 2x - 7"; //bufor nadawania

void usart_inicjuj(void)
{
    //definiowanie parametrów transmisji za pomocą makr zawartych w pliku
    //nagłówkowym setbaud.h. Jeżeli wybierzesz prędkość, która nie będzie
    //możliwa do realizacji otrzymasz ostrzeżenie:
    //#warning "Baud rate achieved is higher than allowed"

    #define BAUD 57600        //tutaj podaj żądaną prędkość transmisji
    #include <util/setbaud.h> //linkowanie tego pliku musi być
    //po zdefiniowaniu BAUD
    
    //ustaw obliczone przez makro wartości
    UBRRH = UBRRH_VALUE;
    UBRRL = UBRRL_VALUE;
    #if USE_2X
    UCSRA |=  (1<<U2X);
    #else
    UCSRA &= ~(1<<U2X);
    #endif


    //Ustawiamy pozostałe parametry moduł USART
    //U W A G A !!!
    //W ATmega8, aby zapisać do rejestru UCSRC należy ustawiać bit URSEL
    //zobacz także: http://mikrokontrolery.blogspot.com/2011/04/avr-czyhajace-pulapki.html#avr_pulapka_2
    UCSRC = (1<<URSEL) | (1<<UCSZ1) | (1<<UCSZ0);  //bitów danych: 8
    //bity stopu:  1
    //parzystość:  brak
    //włącz nadajnik i odbiornik oraz ich przerwania odbiornika
    //przerwania nadajnika włączamy w funkcji wyslij_wynik()
    UCSRB = (1<<TXEN) | (1<<RXEN) | (1<<RXCIE);
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------


ISR(USART_RXC_vect)
{
    //przerwanie generowane po odebraniu bajtu
    odb_x = UDR;   //zapamiętaj odebraną liczbę
    odb_flaga = 1; //ustaw flagę odbioru liczby dla main()
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------

ISR(USART_UDRE_vect){

    //przerwanie generowane, gdy bufor nadawania jest już pusty,
    //odpowiedzialne za wysłanie wszystkich znaków z tablicy usart_bufor[]

    //sprawdzamy, czy bajt do wysłania jest znakiem końca tekstu, czyli zerem
    if(usart_bufor[usart_bufor_ind]!= 0){

        //załaduj znak do rejestru wysyłki i ustaw indeks na następny znak
        UDR = usart_bufor[usart_bufor_ind++];

        }else{

        //osiągnięto koniec napisu w tablicy usart_bufor[]
        UCSRB &= ~(1<<UDRIE); //wyłącz przerwania pustego bufora nadawania
    }
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------


void wyslij_wynik(void){

    //funkcja rozpoczyna wysyłanie, wysyłając pierwszy znak znajdujący się
    //w tablicy usart_bufor[]. Pozostałe wyśle funkcja przerwania,
    //która zostanie wywołana automatycznie po wysłaniu każdego znaku.

    //dodaj do tekstu wyniku znaki końca linii (CR+LF), by na
    //ekranie terminala wyniki pojawiały się w nowych liniach
    unsigned char z;
    for(z=0; z<30; z++){
        if(usart_bufor[z]==0){   //czy to koniec takstu w tablicy
            //tak znaleziono koniec tekstu, dodajemy znak CR
            usart_bufor[z]   = 13;  //znak powrotu karetki CR (Carrige Return)
            usart_bufor[z+1]  = 10; //znak nowej linii LF (Line Feed)
            usart_bufor[z+2]  = 0;  //znak końca ciągu tekstu w tablicy
            break;
        }
    }


    //Zaczekaj, aż bufor nadawania będzie pusty
    while (!(UCSRA & (1<<UDRE)));

    //bufor jest pusty można wysłać

    //następny znak do wysyłki to znak nr 1
    usart_bufor_ind = 0;

    //włącz przerwania pustego bufora UDR, co rozpocznie transmisję
    //aktualnej zawartości bufora
    UCSRB |= (1<<UDRIE);

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------


int main(void)
{
    usart_inicjuj(); //inicjuj moduł USART (RS-232)
    sei();           //włącz przerwania globalne

    wyslij_wynik();  //na początku wysyłamy text wzoru, który po
    //resecie jest w tablicy usart_bufor[]

    while(1){

        //tutaj Twój program ....

        //czekamy na informację o odebraniu danej nie blokując mikrokontrolera
        if(odb_flaga){

            odb_flaga = 0; //zgaś flagę

            //wykonaj obliczenia i wynik przekształć na znaki ładując do
            //bufora usart_bufor[]
            sprintf(usart_bufor, "%f", 0.3187 * odb_x * odb_x + 2 * odb_x - 7);

            wyslij_wynik();  //rozpocznij wysyłanie wyniku przez RS-232
        }

        //w tym czasie można wykonywać dowolny program
        //umieść go tutaj lub przed if() powyżej
    }
}
```

and what he gets in realterm is, among other things, "•Ăeâ‚ ÂŤń•Ăeâ™ ÂŤń"

I want to get normal characters. I have microchip.He would like the equation to be solved after sending a number from the terminal and send the result back.

The code comes from the site :https://mikrokontrolery.blogspot.com/2011/03/rs-232-atmega8-komputer-terminal.html. It connects using Converter CH340G USB RS232 TTL UART USART Arduino

Comment: Is 1Mhz real CPU clock frequency? What is CKSEL3:0 fuse value? What is RealTerm configuration? What commands are used to build the program?

Comment: Write a new program with English comments and identifiers in case you expect others to help you with it. Writing source in ones native language is always a mistake - I never do that even when I suspect that none else but myself will ever read the source.

Comment: Did you try to reduce the program: only initialize UART without interrupts and print a "hello" string. Does it work?

Answer (score 2):

With Fosc 1Mhz and baud rate 57600, the error between the correct baud rate and the baud rate generated by the processor is 8.5%. See table 60 in the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2486-8-bit-AVR-microcontroller-ATmega8_L_datasheet.pdf#page=153). This is too much for the transmitted characters to be correctly evaluated. The solution is either to reduce the transmission speed or to increase the clock frequency of the MCU. Use the table 60 of the DS for the correct selection of the maximum transmission speed. Reliable transmission is achieved if the error is less than 1.5% (details, see e.g. [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/the-uart-baud-rate-clock-how-accurate-does-it-need-to-be/))